# How to display a dynamic message on Clientclick event of Link button inside a grid view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a linkButton in my gridview , whose text can be "Active" or "Inactive".
OnClientClick function of Link button , I want to display a dynamic message.
e.g:

**CASE 1:**

If Text of LinkButton is Active:
Then OnClientClick , I want to display a message "Convert ACTIVE into INACTIVE"

**CASE 2:**

If Text of LinkButton is InActive:
Then OnClientClick , I want to display a message "Convert INACTIVE into ACTIVE"

Comment: Please post some revelant code, your grid structure, what you've tried etc..

Answer (score 0):

Code for you is ....

**jQuery i.e Client script**

you need to write the function as below which checks the text of the link and best on that it raise the confirm message to the end user...

```
function confirmMessage(button)
{
  if ($(button).text() =="Active")
  {
    return confirm("Convert from active to inactive");
  }
  else
  {
    return confirm("Convert from inactive to active");
  }
}
```

**Aspx**

Attach function to linkbutton as fllow..here i hard code "text=Active" which is relace by the eval function ...

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
       <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Active" OnClientClick="return confirmMessage(this);" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Hi Pranay,
When I am trying to execute the above script , it's only executing the second block of confirmMessage() function.
i.e."Convert from inactive to active"

Comment: @palakmehta - just check this line of code if ($(this).attr("text")=="Active")  is to working for you or not...otherwise try to get the innerhtml of button like if ($(this).html()=="Active")  and than check its returning proper value or not...

Comment: function confirmMessage(obj)
{
  if ($(this).attr("text")=="Active")
  {
    return confirm("Convert from active to inactive");
  }
  else
  {
    return confirm("Convert from inactive to active");
  }
}


Hi Pranay,
the code is working fine in Chrome , Mozilla but not on IE.
Please suggest.

Comment: @palakmehta - try my edited code...this will work because there might be issue with tha attr("text") ...

Comment: Pranay rana:After modification , I am facing the same issue.
It's working on Chrome/Mozilla , but not on IE.

Comment: @palakmehta - for me code is working fine on IE also i think you missed something...

Comment: You should be referring to $(button).attr("value") or $(button).val().

Answer (score 0):

First of all all u have to get particular control id when clicks on linkbutton. thereafter u have to know the text of link button then you to change if it is active then Inactive or active.

Ex:

```
     <asp:Button Text='<%#Eval("Type") %>' runat="server" OnClientClick="return changetext(this);" ID="btnType" />
     function changetext(cntl)
    {
        var id = cntl.id;
    var text=$('#id').val();
    var changedtext=text.toLower()=='active'?Inactive:Active;
     text.val(changedtext);
return false;
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

this code may help u..!! template field in the gridview

```
// the below is template field in the gridview all you need to do is add  //OnClientClick="return GetSelectedRow(this) to this
     <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" runat="server"  OnClientClick="return GetSelectedRow(this)" >Select</asp:LinkButton>

                      </ItemTemplate>
//then in javascrpt just write this code
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSelectedRowSalesCapital(lnk) {
                var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;
                var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
                  var text= row.cells[RequiredColumnIndexof link].getElementsById(lnkSelect).value;
               if(text=="Active")
               {
                alert("Convert ACTIVE into INACTIVE");
                 }
                 else if(text=="Inactive")
                 {
                  alert("Convert INACTIVE into ACTIVE ");
                 }
                return false;
            }

</script>
```